# Image Extractor by AI Habitat produces a configuration error when importing Matterport dataset

Tags: dataset, config, simulation

I need help understanding the error message, which is along the lines of changing the file name to json because the configuration fails. I have a long error message but pasted the part that is mostly repeated throughout the message:

/Users/kyra/Documents/GitHub/habitat-sim/matterport/scans/house1/8194nk5LbLH 13/poisson_meshes/8194nk5LbLH_10.stage_config.json
I0412 19:04:17.735939 42397184 AttributesManagerBase.h:296] AttributesManager::createFromJsonOrDefaultInternal  (Stage) : Proposing JSON name : /Users/kyra/Documents/GitHub/habitat-sim/matterport/scans/house1/8194nk5LbLH 13/poisson_meshes/8194nk5LbLH_10.stage_config.json from original name : /Users/kyra/Documents/GitHub/habitat-sim/matterport/scans/house1/8194nk5LbLH 13/poisson_meshes/8194nk5LbLH_10.ply | This file  does not exist.
I0412 19:04:17.736085 42397184 AbstractObjectAttributesManagerBase.h:182] AbstractObjectAttributesManager::createObject  (Stage) : Done making attributes with handle : /Users/kyra/Documents/GitHub/habitat-sim/matterport/scans/house1/8194nk5LbLH 13/poisson_meshes/8194nk5LbLH_10.ply
I0412 19:04:17.736093 42397184 AbstractObjectAttributesManagerBase.h:189] File (/Users/kyra/Documents/GitHub/habitat-sim/matterport/scans/house1/8194nk5LbLH 13/poisson_meshes/8194nk5LbLH_10.ply) exists but is not a recognized config filename extension, so new default Stage attributes created and registered.
I0412 19:04:17.736124 42397184 SceneDatasetAttributes.cpp:46]

What I did: Ran [image extractor](https://aihabitat.org/docs/habitat-sim/image-extractor.html) after activating Conda env. I modified the image extractor to change the file path to point to a .ply file in the matterport dataset.

Setup: 1)Facebook's AI Habitat-sim [built from source](https://github.com/facebookresearch/habitat-sim/blob/master/BUILD_FROM_SOURCE.md),
2)MacBook Air M1,
3)Conda environment with the dependencies (using pip install -r requirements.txt) but habitat-sim is not installed by Conda,
4)Matterport3D dataset (downloaded one house).

Thank you.